# Dish soap nozzle build up

Tags: home, kitchen

How to prevent dish soap bottle from getting clogged by dry soap at the tip of the bottle. The tip of the bottle keeps getting clogged from dry soap substance.

Comment: You can prevent it by closing the lid after use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I purchased washing up liquid in a pump bottle from some fancy manufacturer once, and I've retained the bottle which I now fill up with the regular soap.

I imagine any pump bottle will suffice; in these days of COVID you can probably find any amount of hand wash pump bottles you can refill and a couple of pumps will eject enough soap, plus help use a consistent amount (maybe less) too, if for example the kids just indiscriminately squirt half a bottle of dish soap in when they're "helping"

---

It's a commercial product that exists already but it's possible to buy brushes that have a container in the handle for a large quantity of soap that drips out as the brush is used; this might also help solve the problem as you're using a lot of soap infrequently so there isn't enough small repeated use to cause a buildup

Comment: Wow this solution is so simple but so dam good. I cant believe i didnt think about just putting the dishsoap in a pump bottle like the one i use to wash my hands thank you!!!

Comment: +1 A pump helps reduce wasted detergent by dispensing measured amounts easily.

Answer (score 6):

My trick is to hold the nozzle under the running tap as you fill the sink to wash the dishes. This has the twin benefits if removing the crud, whilst stopping it from being wasted because it contributes to the detergent being used for your washing-up.

There is a bit of an art to it though, you obviously want to avoid excess water getting INTO the bottle, so you will need to experiment with the best angle to hold the bottle to wash away the crud, whilst minimising the entry of water into the bottle. This will also involve the flow of the tap - you need enough water velocity to "mechanically" knock the crud off the bottle, but if the flow is slower, it allows more time for the water to dissolve the detergent. A balancing act.

Comment: This is how I've been handling it.  I like that I can get a tiny amount of soap off of the lid and cap when I don't need a full squirt of dish detergent.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't found a way to avoid it, but this is the easiest way to deal with it:

When the buildup becomes problematic (clogging the nozzle), unscrew the top and drop it in a mug filled with warm water. Leave for a few hours.
The soap mostly dissolves, any remaining crud is easily scrubbed off.

This happens 1-2 times over the life of a bottle.

Comment: Awesome i will try because this is happening like once a month or once every two months